# Getting spam on my Apple email from just one company

Tags: email, hacking, spam

I have an email address that I only use for official communication with the Apple Corporation. I have no phone and have only used this address when registering my iPad and the payment mechanism for buying things in the AppStore.

This email address which I have had for over 10 years is now receiving spam from a single company: "Goodman Capital" which is advertising some kind of investment services. I receive absolutely no other communications on this address except for official Apple correspondence, like password resets and things like that.

Is Apple providing customer emails to third parties or have they been hacked?

The only comparable problem I have had is that the email address I use to communicate with Adobe receives occasional spam, but this is because of a known hack where somebody got access to Adobe's customer records and began selling them on the dark web.

Comment: Enter the email address in https://haveibeenpwned.com/ and see if it's included in any account hacks.  I don't think anyone here can answer if Apple sells the developer email accounts.  I'd be extremely surprised if they did that.

Comment: Is your email address structured in a formulaic way? Some spammers send emails by educated guesses to an entire domain. For example they might send emails to s.handle@domain.com, stale.h@domain.com, and stalehandleapple@domain.com, or any number of other combinations based on responses they've received in the past.

Answer (score 2):

No - Apple doesn't sell out emails and the simple explanation is that this resource just tried all mail addresses possible at Apple and now knows your mail is valid (or doesn't know it's not valid) and will keep spamming it forever since they don't actually have permission or a lead - they're just being nasty like someone that robo calls all the phone numbers possible whether they're in the phone book or not.